# Rails, Twitter Bootstrap, Simple Form, Heroku - Odd error when using ":wrapper => :prepend do" to get an add-on span

Tags: heroku, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have the following code in a form partial:

```
<%= f.association :client %>
<%= f.input :url, :wrapper => :prepend do %>
    <%= content_tag :span, "http://www.", :class => "add-on" %>
    <%= f.input_field :url, :class => 'span4' %>
<% end %>
```

Trying to load anything to do with this form partial e.g. new/edit etc causes Heroku to error. It works flawlessly on localhost.

The only obvious error in the Heroku logs is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `source' for nil:NilClass):
```

I'm afraid I don't really understand that but thought it might help anyone trying to answer this.

If I change the form partial code it works on Heroku no problem at all e.g.

```
<%= f.input :url, :input_html => {:class => 'span4' } %>
```

Obviously I lose my nice bootstrap add-on span so I'd rather find out what the issue is rather than running around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after testing and some help from Dan I finally got to the bottom of it. Unfortunately, it seems to be quite localised to my situation though.

But just in case anyone stumbles across this, the error I had was the following:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `source' for nil:NilClass):
```

That was in the log and was THE SAME when I followed Dan's advise to turn on error reporting on the production site (set `consider_all_requests_local = true` in config/environments/production.rb).

I thought that the error was being caused in the template, however, it was some validation rules in the model. The validation rules for me where some regex to stop the user starting the input with a certain string. They worked perfectly fine on my local, but Heroku really wasn't liking it!

I removed those validation rules and voila, my nice bootstrap add-on span was working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but maybe an initializer that sets up the prepend wrapper (like initializers/simple_form.rb or initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb) is not being run by Heroku, either because it's not checked into git, or because of some environment-specific logic in the initializers or environment files.

Comment: Hi Dan, cheers for having a stab at it. If one of those initializers wasn't running wouldn't the entire app just fall flat on it's face though because essentially every other page works perfectly fine (which all have an abundance of simple form and bootstrap code)? In any case, what would be the best way to check this?

Comment: If you can find the initializer that defines the :prepend wrapper, you could confirm that it's checked into git, and also add a quick `p "ran the initializer"` statement inside it, and then make sure that appears in the Heroku logs.

Comment: Bad news I'm afraid. The initializer (simple_form_bootstrap.rb) was the one holding the :prepend wrapper. I added the p "ran the..." to it and it is indeed in the heroku logs and in git. Slightly off topic but is there a way of overriding the default "We're sorry, but something went wrong." 500.html and displaying more 'development' errors on heroku? Maybe I can get more info from that?

Comment: Yep, you can set `consider_all_requests_local = true` in production.rb.

Comment: I finally found the problem, cheers for the help. Seems like I got a bit unlucky with some regex not playing nicely with Heroku.